# Palisade: EvalMult between plaintext and ciphertext resulting in tower size mismatch

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I hope someone can help me understand an error I get when using Palisades.  I want to only use the first 329 slots of a BGV ciphertext, and zero out the rest (which at some point contains some 'rubbish' I don't want to re-enter the first 329 slots when doing rotations).  So I have created a Plaintext called mask that I fill with 1's in the first 329 slots like this:

```
Plaintext mask;
vector<int64_t> vecMask;
for(int i=0; i<329; ++i)
  vecMask.push_back(1);
mask = cryptoContext->MakePackedPlaintext(vecMask);
```

Later I call EvalMult to zero out everything in a ciphertext C1 except for the 329 first positions:

```
C1=cryptoContext->EvalMult(mask,C1);
```

But when I then later try to add another ciphertext to C1, the following error message occurs:

*tower size mismatch; cannot add*

If the masking is commented out, everything works fine except C1 will contain the rubbish I want removed.  How should I do the masking correctly?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. The ciphertext level must be the same. There are tools for adjusting the levels. Did you look at the examples? Note that this is about the programming aspect of a cryptographic library and therefore should be asked at [so] with the proper tags at least; cryptography, encryption, and the programing language

Comment: Hi Havard, I can migrate this for you to StackOverflow if you so wish, but you will have to also join SO to handle it further over there. Error messages of crypto related applications are not on topic here. Just flag your question if you want migration.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take the question to StackOverflow then.  And thanks for the tip about ciphertext levels, maybe that will clarify things!

Comment: moved to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67485806/palisade-evalmult-between-plaintext-and-ciphertext-resulting-in-tower-size-mism